# Menu items doesnt shown on my panel

Tags: extjs, ext.net

can someone tell me why I cant see my menuitem inside the menupanel,I guess I do wrong something but not figure out yet.
thank you

```
  @Html.X().ResourceManager()
  @(

        Html.X().Panel().Layout(LayoutType.Border).Title("TITLE").Icon(Icon.Anchor).Height(550)
        .Items(
        Html.X().Panel().Layout(LayoutType.Accordion).Title("border")
        .Icon(Icon.ApplicationAdd)
        .Region(Region.West)
        .Width(250)
        .Items(
        Html.X().MenuPanel().Title("TITLE").Items(

                Html.X().Menu().Items(
                Html.X().MenuItem().Text("1").Icon(Icon.Add),
                Html.X().MenuItem().Text("2").Icon(Icon.Add),
                Html.X().MenuItem().Text("3").Icon(Icon.Add)

        )))

        ,

         Html.X().Panel().Layout(LayoutType.Fit).Title("CENTER")
        .Icon(Icon.ApplicationAdd)
        .Region(Region.Center)

        )

  )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem like this

```
                            Html.X().MenuPanel()
                                .Collapsed(true)
                                .Icon(Icon.Note)
                                .AutoScroll(true)
                                .Title("menu")
                                .ID("PNL34")
                                .BodyPadding(0)
                                .Menu(menu => {

                                    menu.Items.Add(Html.X().MenuItem().ID("1a").Text("test1").Icon(Icon.Anchor)
                                   .DirectEvents(m => { m.Click.Url = "Desktop/AddTab";
                                   m.Click.ExtraParams.Add(new { conid = "TabPanel1" ,pnlid="tabpnl10",viewname="Urunler"});
                                        }));


                                    menu.Items.Add(Html.X().MenuItem().ID("2a").Text("test2").Icon(Icon.Anchor)
                                  .DirectEvents(m =>
                                  {
                                      m.Click.Url = "Desktop/AddTab";
                                      m.Click.ExtraParams.Add(new { conid = "TabPanel1", pnlid = "tabpnl11", viewname = "Siparisler" });
                                  }));
```